# Msbuild not copying a ProjectReference to bin folder

Tags: dll, build, msbuild, bin

To prevent circular dependency, i had to make a reference from (lets say) project A, to B's bin folder. When i run a rebuild or build in Visual Studio it creates bin folder and required dll references by A, under B project.

But msbuild command does not work that way. It does not create bin and dlls under B. I investigate the problem, found some solutions like using dummy class user method to make msbuild copy references under bin. But it did not work too.

Project A -> Project B/bin/C Dlls ->Project C

Project C Dlls required by Project A.

What do i have to do to make msbuild command create bin folder under B project?

Comment: You're not preventing a circular dependency, you're propagating it by circumventing the safeguards.  The only real solution is to refactor the projects to remove the circular dependency.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I had to refactor all the project hierarchy and problem solved that way. You can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the circular dependency is still present.  It has only been circumvented by going directly to the bin folder.  This bypasses the safeguards that call out a circular dependency at build time.

As a general rule, if you need to go directly to the bin folder then there's a problem.

I suggest refactoring the projects to remove the circular dependency.